# Is there a way to call a function recursively from tactic mode or from match expressions in Lean?

Tags: lean

Attempt #1:

```
def sget' {α : Type} {n : ℕ} (i : ℕ) {h1 : n > 0} {h2 : i < n} (s: sstack α n) : α :=
begin
  cases n with n0 nn,
  begin
    have f : false, from nat.lt_asymm h1 h1,
    tauto,
  end,
  induction s,
  cases s_val,
  begin
    have : stack.empty.size = 0, from @stack_size_0 α,
    tauto,
  end,
  cases i with i0 ri,
  exact s_val_x,
  exact sget' (pred i) s_val_s,
end
```

Attempt #2:

```
def sget' {α : Type} {n : ℕ} (i : ℕ) {h1 : n > 0} {h2 : i < n} (s: sstack α n) : α :=
match i, s with
  | 0, ⟨stack.push x s, _⟩ := x
  | i, ⟨stack.push _ s, _⟩ := sget' (pred i) ⟨s, _⟩
  | _, ⟨stack.empty, _⟩    := sorry  -- just ignore this
```

Lean in both cases throws `unknown identifier sget'` error. I know that I can call `sget'` recursively from ehh pattern guards (not sure how they are properly called), but is there any way to do something like that with tactics and/or match expressions?

Comment: The `induction` tactic gives you an inductive hypothesis which is what you're supposed to be using instead of `pred i`. But it's not a good idea to define data using tactic mode in general. Your attempt 2 -- why not just use the equation compiler directly on i and s? I agree that match can't be used with sget' the way you're trying to do it.

Comment: It's much easier for us to help with Lean questions if you post a [minimal working example](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mwe.html) (e.g. something without `sstack`) that works besides the issue you're asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do recursive calls if you use the equation compiler

```
def map (f : α → β) : list α → list β
| [] := []
| (a :: l) := f a :: map l
```

Otherwise you should use `induction` tactic or one of the explicit recursor functions (like `nat.rec`).